# Merge two multi-level JSONs and convert them from one format to another format

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript

I have two JSONs which needs to be merged and then converted into another format using TypeScript in React.
I was initially running a recursive call of a function to do this, and also tried reducer, but it doesn't work.

I have looked into many solutions, and all of them are based on one level of JSON, whereas as the example I have provided has multiple levels.

> Please note that JSON 1 and JSON 2 have same formats, but their nested children can be of any levels deep. Also resulting JSON should have a dummy parent or root JSON which has these two JSONs as children, but in different format.

### EDIT 2:

In this example I have shown only two JSONs, but in reality there are multiple JSONs located within an array object and these JSONs can be of any level of deep using the "childPages" node.

Can someone help me with this please?

## JSON 1

```
{
    "section_id": "01",
    "title": "R1",
    "description": "Optional",
    "childPages": [
        {
            "section_id": "0101",
            "title": "R1C1",
            "description": "Optional",
            "childPages": []
        },
        {
            "section_id": "0102",
            "title": "R1C2",
            "description": "Optional",
            "childPages": []
        },
        {
            "section_id": "0103",
            "title": "R1C3",
            "description": "Optional",
            "childPages": []
        },
        {
            "section_id": "0104",
            "title": "R1C4",
            "description": "Optional",
            "childPages": [
                {
                    "section_id": "010401",
                    "title": "R1C4R1",
                    "description": "Optional",
                    "childPages": []
                },
                {
                    "section_id": "010402",
                    "title": "R1C4R2",
                    "description": "Optional",
                    "childPages": []
                },
                {
                    "section_id": "010403",
                    "title": "R1C4R3",
                    "description": "Optional",
                    "childPages": []
                },
                {
                    "section_id": "010404",
                    "title": "R1C4R5",
                    "description": "Optional",
                    "childPages": []
                },
                {
                    "section_id": "010405",
                    "title": "R1C4R6",
                    "description": "Optional",
                    "childPages": []
                },
                {
                    "section_id": "010406",
                    "title": "R1C4R7",
                    "description": "Optional",
                    "childPages": []
                },
                {
                    "section_id": "010407",
                    "title": "R1C4R8",
                    "description": "Optional",
                    "childPages": []
                },
                {
                    "section_id": "010408",
                    "title": "R1C4R9",
                    "description": "Optional",
                    "childPages": [
                        {
                            "section_id": "01040801",
                            "title": "R1C4R9C1",
                            "description": "Optional",
                            "childPages": []
                        },
                        {
                            "section_id": "01040802",
                            "title": "R1C4R9C2",
                            "description": "Optional",
                            "childPages": []
                        },
                        {
                            "section_id": "01040803",
                            "title": "R1C4R9C3",
                            "description": "Optional",
                            "childPages": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

## JSON 2

```
{
    "section_id": "02",
    "title": "R2",
    "description": "Optional",
    "childPages": [
        {
            "section_id": "0201",
            "title": "R2C1",
            "description": "Optional",
            "childPages": []
        },
        {
            "section_id": "0202",
            "title": "R2C2",
            "description": "Optional",
            "childPages": []
        },
        {
            "section_id": "0203",
            "title": "R2C3",
            "description": "Optional",
            "childPages": []
        },
        {
            "section_id": "0204",
            "title": "R2C4",
            "description": "Optional",
            "childPages": [
                {
                    "section_id": "020401",
                    "title": "R2C4R1",
                    "description": "Optional",
                    "childPages": []
                },
                {
                    "section_id": "020402",
                    "title": "R2C4R2",
                    "description": "Optional",
                    "childPages": []
                },
                {
                    "section_id": "020403",
                    "title": "R2C4R3",
                    "description": "Optional",
                    "childPages": []
                },
                {
                    "section_id": "020404",
                    "title": "R2C4R5",
                    "description": "Optional",
                    "childPages": []
                },
                {
                    "section_id": "020405",
                    "title": "R2C4R6",
                    "description": "Optional",
                    "childPages": []
                },
                {
                    "section_id": "020406",
                    "title": "R2C4R7",
                    "description": "Optional",
                    "childPages": []
                },
                {
                    "section_id": "020407",
                    "title": "R2C4R8",
                    "description": "Optional",
                    "childPages": []
                },
                {
                    "section_id": "020408",
                    "title": "R2C4R9",
                    "description": "Optional",
                    "childPages": [
                        {
                            "section_id": "02040801",
                            "title": "R2C4R9C1",
                            "description": "Optional",
                            "childPages": []
                        },
                        {
                            "section_id": "02040802",
                            "title": "R2C4R9C2",
                            "description": "Optional",
                            "childPages": []
                        },
                        {
                            "section_id": "02040803",
                            "title": "R2C4R9C3",
                            "description": "Optional",
                            "childPages": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

## Output should be:

```
let treeItems = [
    {
        key: "00",
        label: "Root",
        subLabel: "Optional",
        children: [
            {
                key: "01",
                label: "R1",
                subLabel: "Optional",
                children: [
                    {
                        key: "0101",
                        label: "R1C1",
                        subLabel: "Optional",
                        children: []
                    },
                    {
                        key: "0102",
                        label: "R1C2",
                        subLabel: "Optional",
                        children: []
                    },
                    {
                        key: "0103",
                        label: "R1C3",
                        subLabel: "Optional",
                        children: []
                    },
                    {
                        key: "0104",
                        label: "R1C4",
                        subLabel: "Optional",
                        children: [
                            {
                                key: "010401",
                                label: "R1C4R1",
                                subLabel: "Optional",
                                children: []
                            },
                            {
                                key: "010402",
                                label: "R1C4R2",
                                subLabel: "Optional",
                                children: []
                            },
                            {
                                key: "010403",
                                label: "R1C4R3",
                                subLabel: "Optional",
                                children: []
                            },
                            {
                                key: "010404",
                                label: "R1C4R5",
                                subLabel: "Optional",
                                children: []
                            },
                            {
                                key: "010405",
                                label: "R1C4R6",
                                subLabel: "Optional",
                                children: []
                            },
                            {
                                key: "010406",
                                label: "R1C4R7",
                                subLabel: "Optional",
                                children: []
                            },
                            {
                                key: "010407",
                                label: "R1C4R8",
                                subLabel: "Optional",
                                children: []
                            },
                            {
                                key: "010408",
                                label: "R1C4R9",
                                subLabel: "Optional",
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        key: "01040801",
                                        label: "R1C4R9C1",
                                        subLabel: "Optional",
                                        children: []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        key: "01040802",
                                        label: "R1C4R9C2",
                                        subLabel: "Optional",
                                        children: []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        key: "01040803",
                                        label: "R1C4R9C3",
                                        subLabel: "Optional",
                                        children: []
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                key: "02",
                label: "R2",
                subLabel: "Optional",
                children: [
                    {
                        key: "0201",
                        label: "R2C1",
                        subLabel: "Optional",
                        children: []
                    },
                    {
                        key: "0202",
                        label: "R2C2",
                        subLabel: "Optional",
                        children: []
                    },
                    {
                        key: "0203",
                        label: "R2C3",
                        subLabel: "Optional",
                        children: []
                    },
                    {
                        key: "0204",
                        label: "R2C4",
                        subLabel: "Optional",
                        children: [
                            {
                                key: "020401",
                                label: "R2C4R1",
                                subLabel: "Optional",
                                children: []
                            },
                            {
                                key: "020402",
                                label: "R2C4R2",
                                subLabel: "Optional",
                                children: []
                            },
                            {
                                key: "020403",
                                label: "R2C4R3",
                                subLabel: "Optional",
                                children: []
                            },
                            {
                                key: "020404",
                                label: "R2C4R5",
                                subLabel: "Optional",
                                children: []
                            },
                            {
                                key: "020405",
                                label: "R2C4R6",
                                subLabel: "Optional",
                                children: []
                            },
                            {
                                key: "020406",
                                label: "R2C4R7",
                                subLabel: "Optional",
                                children: []
                            },
                            {
                                key: "020407",
                                label: "R2C4R8",
                                subLabel: "Optional",
                                children: []
                            },
                            {
                                key: "020408",
                                label: "R2C4R9",
                                subLabel: "Optional",
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        key: "02040801",
                                        label: "R2C4R9C1",
                                        subLabel: "Optional",
                                        children: []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        key: "02040802",
                                        label: "R2C4R9C2",
                                        subLabel: "Optional",
                                        children: []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        key: "02040803",
                                        label: "R2C4R9C3",
                                        subLabel: "Optional",
                                        children: []
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this would be helpful.

```js
const JSON1 = {
  section_id: "01",
  title: "R1",
  description: "Optional",
  childPages: [
    {
      section_id: "0101",
      title: "R1C1",
      description: "Optional",
      childPages: [],
    },
    {
      section_id: "0102",
      title: "R1C2",
      description: "Optional",
      childPages: [],
    },
    {
      section_id: "0103",
      title: "R1C3",
      description: "Optional",
      childPages: [],
    },
    {
      section_id: "0104",
      title: "R1C4",
      description: "Optional",
      childPages: [
        {
          section_id: "010401",
          title: "R1C4R1",
          description: "Optional",
          childPages: [],
        },
        {
          section_id: "010402",
          title: "R1C4R2",
          description: "Optional",
          childPages: [],
        },
        {
          section_id: "010403",
          title: "R1C4R3",
          description: "Optional",
          childPages: [],
        },
        {
          section_id: "010404",
          title: "R1C4R5",
          description: "Optional",
          childPages: [],
        },
        {
          section_id: "010405",
          title: "R1C4R6",
          description: "Optional",
          childPages: [],
        },
        {
          section_id: "010406",
          title: "R1C4R7",
          description: "Optional",
          childPages: [],
        },
        {
          section_id: "010407",
          title: "R1C4R8",
          description: "Optional",
          childPages: [],
        },
        {
          section_id: "010408",
          title: "R1C4R9",
          description: "Optional",
          childPages: [
            {
              section_id: "01040801",
              title: "R1C4R9C1",
              description: "Optional",
              childPages: [],
            },
            {
              section_id: "01040802",
              title: "R1C4R9C2",
              description: "Optional",
              childPages: [],
            },
            {
              section_id: "01040803",
              title: "R1C4R9C3",
              description: "Optional",
              childPages: [],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  };

  const JSON2 = {
  section_id: "02",
  title: "R2",
  description: "Optional",
  childPages: [
    {
      section_id: "0201",
      title: "R2C1",
      description: "Optional",
      childPages: [],
    },
    {
      section_id: "0202",
      title: "R2C2",
      description: "Optional",
      childPages: [],
    },
    {
      section_id: "0203",
      title: "R2C3",
      description: "Optional",
      childPages: [],
    },
    {
      section_id: "0204",
      title: "R2C4",
      description: "Optional",
      childPages: [
        {
          section_id: "020401",
          title: "R2C4R1",
          description: "Optional",
          childPages: [],
        },
        {
          section_id: "020402",
          title: "R2C4R2",
          description: "Optional",
          childPages: [],
        },
        {
          section_id: "020403",
          title: "R2C4R3",
          description: "Optional",
          childPages: [],
        },
        {
          section_id: "020404",
          title: "R2C4R5",
          description: "Optional",
          childPages: [],
        },
        {
          section_id: "020405",
          title: "R2C4R6",
          description: "Optional",
          childPages: [],
        },
        {
          section_id: "020406",
          title: "R2C4R7",
          description: "Optional",
          childPages: [],
        },
        {
          section_id: "020407",
          title: "R2C4R8",
          description: "Optional",
          childPages: [],
        },
        {
          section_id: "020408",
          title: "R2C4R9",
          description: "Optional",
          childPages: [
            {
              section_id: "02040801",
              title: "R2C4R9C1",
              description: "Optional",
              childPages: [],
            },
            {
              section_id: "02040802",
              title: "R2C4R9C2",
              description: "Optional",
              childPages: [],
            },
            {
              section_id: "02040803",
              title: "R2C4R9C3",
              description: "Optional",
              childPages: [],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
 };
 
function childPages(item) {
  let arr = [];
  item.map((ele) => {
    const obj = {
      key: ele.section_id,
      label: ele.title,
      subLabel: ele.description,
      children: ele.childPages.length ? childPages(ele.childPages) : [],
    };
    arr.push(obj);
  });
  return arr;
}

function func(data) {
  let chlidPagesArr = [], newArr = [];
  const result = data.map(d => Array(d).map(ele => {
    ele.childPages.forEach((item) => {
        const obj = {
          key: item.section_id,
          label: item.title,
          subLabel: item.description,
          children: item.childPages.length
            ? childPages(item.childPages)
            : [],
        };
        chlidPagesArr.push(obj);
      });
      return {
        key: ele.section_id,
        label: ele.title,
        subLabel: ele.description,
        children: chlidPagesArr,
      };
  }))
  if (result.length > 0) {
    result.forEach(item => {
      item.forEach(item1 => {
        newArr.push(item1);
      })
    })
    return newArr;
  } else {
    return result;
  }
}

const JSONS = [JSON1, JSON2];
const finalFormat = func(JSONS);
const result = [
  {
    key: "00",
    label: "Root",
    subLabel: "Optional",
    children: finalFormat,
  },
];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a solution which should work but your function assumes there are only two arrays, but what if there are many JSONs instead of only two?. It's my mistake that I should have mentioned that there are many JSONs within an array.

Comment: Are you talking about the `chlidpages` array, which are also located in JSON1 and JSON2? and if you are asking about the `func` then this is a normal `func` because I made this `func` according to both your arrays and it will work on any array but the array format `JSON1` and `JSON2` must be consistent.

Comment: The JSON 1 and JSON 2 are in-fact part of a larger array object. There can by n number of JSONs which needs to be merged and then converted into the final format. The multiple levels use the "childPages" node.

Comment: HI @Kannan I have updated the answer according to your requirement.